# Bug in featured tab questions counter

Tags: bug, status-norepro, bountied-tab

[Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com) shows 9 featured:
[image]

But when I click on featured tab, it shows 10 featured.

Comment: It's probably cached.

Comment: Showing 10 now.

Comment: @Oded if it's indeed cached (something you can easily confirm) is't it simply by design?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - we tend to mark transient things like this as no-repro, though, yes, by-design is also applicable.

Comment: @Oded fair enough, just being picky. :-)